# Central Air Unit not Sending Enough Power to Thermostat

Tags: hvac, thermostat, central-air, low-voltage

Right now I don't have specifics on my central air unit (make, model, etc) but hopefully the info I provide will help.

I have a Second Generation (and Third Generation) Nest Thermostat hooked up to the Central Air Unit.  I receive intermittent messages of "not enough power" being sent to the thermostat.   (The reason I mentioned both Nests is that I've tried both units).

The wire contains one hot wire (Rh), one for the fan (G), and one for the cool/compressor (Y1).

I used a multimeter to test the voltage, and when I touch the positive probe (red wire) to the Rh wire and the negative probe to the G1 wire,  I get a strong enough reading (between 27-28 volts).  But when I do the same to the Y1 wire I get next to nothing.

After some research, I found people recommending changing the fuse in the unit itself... but when I lifted the panel, I didn't see any fuses that could be replaced.  Moreover, the power drain doesn't seem to be consistent (i.e. today it is showing a poor voltage reading and tomorrow it will be fine).

I don't believe its the Nest because I've tried different ones and get the same results.  Sorry for the long question, but I wanted to be specific.  Any ideas on what is causing the power generation problem?

Comment: We'll have to know the make and model of the air handler and condensing unit.  It would also help if you could provide a clear photo or diagram of the wiring in the air handler.

Comment: OK thanks.  I'll try to take as many pictures as I can.

Comment: If it's an A/C only system, you should have the "hot" wire connected to `Rc` not `Rh`. Though I'm not sure that really matters with the NEST.

Comment: It is an A/C only system.  NEST recommends Rh but through troubleshooting tried seating the hot wire in Rc and yielded the same results.

Comment: How difficult would it be to run a new cable between the thermostat and the air handler?  Are there any extra wires in the existing cable?

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but I'm not sure what you mean by "Are there any extra wires in the existing cable?" I don't think so, within the casing there are three wires only (Red/hot wire, Green/fan wire and White/cool wire).  There are no jumper cables either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39893/discussion-between-mjt117-and-tester101).

Comment: You say you have a 2nd AND 3rd generation nest hooked up?  Do you mean to the same unit?  Is it zoned?

Comment: He means he tried a 2nd gen, didn't work, so he replaced it with a 3rd gen.

Answer (score 1):

This is the most common problem with the Nest.  You need to hook up a "C" wire.

Here's the thing. Originally, thermostats were passive devices - nothing more than switches.   And so, controls were wired in a "switch loop" similar to how switches in houses were wired before current electrical code.  Power went in a functional loop: from the 24V transformer, to the thermostat, to the actuator, and back to the transformer.

The `R` wire is sorta like a "hot" wire, the other wires at the thermostat are sorta like "switched hot". And just like a switch loop doesn't have or need a neutral, neither does the thermostat (the neutral would be the `C` wire).

Old style dimmers and motion sensors powered themsleves by leaking a bit of power through the incandescent bulb.  That fails with efficient CFLs or LEDs.  Likewise, the Nest tries to power itself without a `C` wire by leaking a bit of power through the big clunky old relay that switches on the furnace, fan or A/C.  That fails with efficient relays or electronic controls.

In this situation, you need to run a `C` wire, as the Nest manual discusses.  Tester101 is proposing that you may have spare wires in your thermostat cable.

There are other ways to solve the problem, but they're starting to resemble electrical engineering.

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing where the control board even is... I think it's within the same panel as the main air vent. It's a Luxaire Model No. NAMB-FED14AA

Comment: There may not be a control board.  There will, however, be a transformer.  It might be nearer the fan.  There will certainly be a wire from the fan relay to the transformer, so if necessary, follow the wires from the fan to the relay to the transformer.

Comment: Apologies, that was a misleading comment from yesterday and it should be ignored.  I went back up into the attic and found the control board.  So to clarify a few things: Re: running a common wire--this may end up being the answer but the reason I don't think this is the Nest doesn't always show the e74 (not enough power) issue.  It comes and goes, which leads me to think of a loose connection at the control board because I've stripped and re-seated the wires within the thermostat terminals numerous times.  I would think if it need the C-wire it would just show the error at all times.

Comment: I suspected the Y1 as the loose wire culprit since that was the one giving me the bad voltage reading with the multimeter.  When I opened the unit this is how the wires were configured (FYI i removed the wire nut before taking the picture):   https://goo.gl/vL5l8l    So I assumed I would see the white wires connected to the control board itself rather than jumped together like that.  It was the TIGHTEST inter-coiling i've ever seen so i cut off the ends and interlocked them and nutted it.  FOR NOW the thermostat is showing a solid reading & see if it lasts.  Model info: https://goo.gl/cMPjwN

Comment: There's nothing wrong with pigtailing off the control board, that way you can service the wires without messing with the control board. I would expect the Nest to indicate low power intermittently, that would vary by the state-of-charge of its battery.  I can't see the pics, it hits me with a login challenge, but if a wire is not binding well, that would do it.  Good chance you nailed it!

Comment: Damn... I need to find a way to attach that picture because when I came home from work tonight I got the same error on the Nest again. So whenever I mess with the wires it works for like a day then goes back to saying it has no power. I think this definitely means I need to run a common wire but it's not obvious to me where it would connect in the control board. Do you think the common wire will solve my problem? I just don't understand why after 2 years of having a nest that now all of a sudden I'm having this issue.

Comment: One more update.. I've done nothing with this and the thermostat is showing a good reading to the point where the AC actually kicked on.  I'm stumped.

Comment: Well, like I say, the Nest scavenges off the circuit, and if the current flow is a little too small to scavenge, the Nest will have trouble *sometimes*, mainly relating to the state-of-charge of its battery.  And that will change very slowly as the battery ages.  That might explain why it suddenly started becoming marginal now, as 2 years is midlife or worse for a lithium battery.  Did anything else change?

Comment: Well I originally had a 2nd gen Nest there and started getting the same power error.  To troubleshoot I swapped out that Nest with a 3rd generation Nest and it's doing the same thing.  The third gen Nest is only about 6 months old.  I want to attach the picture of my control board so I can show you where I think the common wire would go but would appreciate a second opinion.  Does this work?  https://goo.gl/photos/EQB5r41u8v9c9fsQ8

Comment: Well two nights ago I ran new thermostat wire and added a common.  The thermostat is working great... But now the condensing unit isn't turning on.  Very frustrating I'm going to have to throw up the white flag and call someone now.